# Exluding "pages" from query_posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, jquery-post

I have a page that lists all posts with a certain category "news".  The first result is always itself - the page!  The page doesn't even have a category but for some reason is listed as one.  I only want to retrieve 'posts'.

My query is:

```
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
```

The resulting page can be seen here:

http://vl.social-gamer.com/news-blog/

I appreciate any help.  I'm a bit of a WP noob still.

Thanks!

Comment: You just then want to get all "posts" of a certain category rather than all "pages"?

Comment: That's correct @cereallarceny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is just get a list of categories, then I'd suggest a function already inside of Wordpress called `wp_list_categories()`.  [Here's the documentation on that particular function.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

> Displays a list of Categories as links. When a Category link is
>   clicked, all the posts in that Category will display on a Category
>   Page using the appropriate Category Template dictated by the Template
>   Hierarchy rules.

Keep in mind, this will also `echo` out the categories, not just retrieve them.  I find myself using this function quite often:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
```

However, if you're looking to find just the "posts" of a certain category and not the "pages" as well then understand that pages in Wordpress are nearly the same thing as posts in Wordpress.  Pages for one can't have a category, but posts can.  Posts are sorted by date, and pages are not.  There's some discrepancies, but for all intents and purposes, there's not a huge difference in how you should code between the two.  [Here's some more information on that discussion.](http://www.johnhaydon.com/2010/03/wordpress-posts-vs-pages-everything-need-know/)

**EDIT**

The author of the post appears to have this problem due to an improper file structure.  For references to a good fule structure [please see this link](http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/25/wordpress-theme-template-directory-structure-tutorial/).

> **index.php**
> **header.php**
> **sidebar.php**
> **footer.php**
> **functions.php**
> **style.css**
> **page.php** <-- This isn't in the article from the link, but it should be added to decide between a page layout of a page of posts layout.

Comment: Your comment above was correct.  The problem is that right now I'm getting 'posts' AND 'pages' @cereallarceny

Comment: If you visit http://vl.social-gamer.com/news-blog/ the top item listed is itself!  A page.

Comment: That's the odd thing because I know that it can't have a category.

Comment: What file in your Wordpress template are you editing to have this error?  Is it index.php?

Comment: I have a template page and functions.php.

The line in the first post is from functions.php

Comment: I bet that the reason for your error is because you aren't depicting which layout is for pages and which layout is for posts.  I'd suggest following this: http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/25/wordpress-theme-template-directory-structure-tutorial/ and then adding a page.php to that.  page.php = pages, index.php = list of posts, single.php = single blog post, etc.